# Bootstrap3 migration failed

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I was using this code to create a ruler on my site:

CSS:

```
.ruler, .ruler li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
/* IE6-7 Fix */
.ruler, .ruler li {
    *display: inline;
}
.ruler {
    background: lightYellow;
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 1em hsl(60, 60%, 84%) inset;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    color: #ccc;
    margin: 0;
    height: 3em;
    padding-right: 1cm;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.ruler li {
    padding-left: 1cm;
    width: 2em;
    margin: .64em -1em -.64em;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px hsl(60, 60%, 84%);
}
.ruler li:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    height: .64em;
    top: -.64em;
    right: 1em;
}

/* Make me pretty! */
body {
    font: 12px Ubuntu, Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 20px;
}

div {
    margin-top: 2em;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="ruler"><li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li><li>4</li></ul>
```

It was working OK with bootstrap2:

http://jsfiddle.net/Uvt5U/4/

Now I'm migrating to bootstrap3 and the ruler is broken:

http://jsfiddle.net/Uvt5U/

How can I get it working?
Kind Regards.

Comment: How is this even relevant to bootstrap, ruler isn't a bootstrap class...

Comment: @Patsy Issa, there are default styles for most of tags. @author, I found that if you increase `.ruler li`'s `width` to `1,64cm`, it works. It's not an answer, but a tip. :)

Comment: @dragoste not the ul tag.

Comment: @Patsy Issa, see my answer. `*` means `<ul>` too ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because in Bootstrap 3 `box-sizing` style is set to `border-box`, while in Bootstrap 2 it's not.

My Firebug points me that this rule is setting this style:

```
*, *:before, *:after {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

bootstrap.min.css line 9

Comment: So, the working code with @dragoste hint here, thank you: http://jsfiddle.net/Uvt5U/6/